# Programmatically selecting UITableView row from other than main thread

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView controller that in viewDidLoad I make a network request asynchronously that calls back to a UITableView method.  If the data contains matching info that is preselected by the user, I would like to advance to the next view controller.  Here is the code I'm using in the callback to advance to the next view controller:

```
 //search for row if it exists, then:
 let indexPath = IndexPath(row: r, section: 0)
 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
     self.tableView.reloadData()
     self.tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false,     
                             scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
     self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
 })
```

When I call the self.tableView(didSelectRowAt: indexPath) I get a a run time failure with not a very helpful stack trace.  Is there something I need to be setting prior to programmatically selecting a row of the UITableView?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

If you want to programmatically trigger a selection of a row in a tableView, you'll have to call it like this:

```
self.tableView.delegate?.tableView!(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```

Your tableView does not have the method `didSelectRowAt`, the delegate does, and it doing so above calls it.

Also don't forget to set the tableView's delegate first to the current view controller, *if that's your desired delegate.*

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks.  That however causes the same SIGABRT in main.  Looks like the problem was I had not overridden tableView(_, didSelectRowAt: ) but it was not found as a compile time error.